# removing object with user_clear causing CTD

Tags: python, mesh

I'm currently doing a project which requires multiple different objects of the same type being created one after the other. I encountered a problem where the first object "must have zero users to be deleted". Thought that using the user_clear function would solve this but it causes a crash to desktop. Have made a simple example to demonstrate the problem. If anyone's got any idea what the issue is it'd be a great help, thanks.

```
import bpy


# Clears all existing objects and meshes
def clearScene():
    for obj in bpy.data.objects:
        if obj.name.startswith("Cube"):
            #obj.user_clear() UNCOMMENT ME!
            bpy.data.objects.remove(obj)
    for mesh in bpy.data.meshes:
        bpy.data.meshes.remove(mesh)

class myCube:
    def __init__(self,size,pos):
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(radius=size/2,location=pos)


myCubes = []
x = 0

for i in range(0,9):
    clearScene()
    c = myCube(2,(x,0,0))
    myCubes.append(c)
    x += 1
```

## Script

```
import bpy
import bmesh
import math
import random

# Needs to be accessed in a few places
EDGE_LENGTH = 0.4

# List to save successful individuals to
viableIndividuals = []

# Clears all existing objects and meshes
def clearScene(curvename):
    #bpy.context.scene.objects.link(bpy.data.objects[curvename])
    meshes = bpy.data.meshes
    curves = bpy.data.curves
    for obj in bpy.data.objects:
        if obj.name.startswith("Curve"):
            cu = obj.data
            print(cu.users)
            bpy.context.scene.objects.unlink(obj)
            obj.user_clear()
            bpy.data.objects.remove(obj)
            curves.remove(cu)
        elif obj.name.startswith("Cube"):
            mu = obj.data
            bpy.context.scene.objects.unlink(obj)
            bpy.data.objects.remove(obj)
            meshes.remove(mu)

# Set number of CPs and their coords
def setCoords(num, list):
    for i in range(0,(num-4)): # -4 to account for the station
        x = random.uniform(-9,9)
        y = random.uniform(-9,9)
        z = random.uniform(-1,5)
        w = random.randrange(1,4)
        list.append((x,y,z,w))

# Check internal angles to determine if physically possible
def calcAngle(cpA,cpB,cpC):
    # Calculate directional vectors for angle ABC
    AB = [(cpB[0]-cpA[0]),(cpB[1]-cpA[1]),(cpB[2]-cpA[2])]
    CB = [(cpB[0]-cpC[0]),(cpB[1]-cpC[1]),(cpB[2]-cpC[2])]

    # Find dot product and magnitudes
    dProd = (AB[0]*CB[0]) + (AB[1]*CB[1]) + (AB[2]*CB[2])
    magAB = math.sqrt((AB[0]*AB[0]) + (AB[1]*AB[1]) + (AB[2]*AB[2]))
    magCB = math.sqrt((CB[0]*CB[0]) + (CB[1]*CB[1]) + (CB[2]*CB[2]))

    # Use product and arc-cos to find internal angle
    angle = 100 * math.acos(dProd/(magAB*magCB))
    return angle

class CollSphere:
    def __init__(self, size, loc):
        self.x = loc[0]
        self.y = loc[1]
        self.z = loc[2]
        self.radius = size
    def intersect(self, sphere):
        distance = math.sqrt((self.x - sphere.x) * (self.x - sphere.x) + (self.y - sphere.y) * (self.y - sphere.y) + (self.z - sphere.z) * (self.z - sphere.z))
    return distance < (self.radius + sphere.radius)

class NURBSCurve:
def __init__(self, name, size, start):
    self.curve_name = name
    self.coords = start
    setCoords(size, self.coords)        

    # Lock end of curve to return to 'station'
    self.coords.append(((start[1][0]*-1),start[1][1],start[1][2],start[1][3]))
    self.coords.append(((start[0][0]*-1),start[0][1],start[0][2],start[0][3]))

    # Create the curve Datablock
    self.curveData = bpy.data.curves.new(self.curve_name, type='CURVE')
    self.curveData.dimensions = '3D'
    self.curveData.resolution_u = 2

    self.curveObj = bpy.data.objects.new(self.curve_name, self.curveData)

def buildCurve(self):
    # Map polyline to curve
    polyline = self.curveData.splines.new('NURBS')
    polyline.points.add(len(self.coords))
    for i, coord in enumerate(self.coords):
        x,y,z,w = coord
        polyline.points[i].co = (x, y, z, w)

    polyline.order_u = 5
    self.curveObj = bpy.data.objects.new(self.curve_name, self.curveData)
    self.curveData.splines[0].use_cyclic_u = True

    # Attach to scene and validate context
    bpy.context.scene.objects.link(self.curveObj)
    #bpy.context.scene.objects.active = curveObj
    #curveObj.select = True

def length(self):
    len_mesh = self.curveObj.to_mesh(scene=bpy.context.scene,apply_modifiers=False,settings='PREVIEW')
    bm = bmesh.new()
    bm.from_mesh(len_mesh,face_normals=True,use_shape_key=True)

    lgth = 0
    for edge in bm.edges:
        lgth += edge.calc_length() # Existing function for meshes

    #print(lgth)
    return lgth

def fill(self):
    # 'Fill-out' curve so it can be viewed better (get rid later)
    self.curveData.bevel_depth = 0.05   
    self.curveData.fill_mode = 'FULL'
    self.curveData.resolution_u = 10
    self.curveData.bevel_resolution = 5

def collCubes(self):
    # Cube which will be used to detect track collisions
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(location=(0,0,0), radius=EDGE_LENGTH/2)

    coll_cube = bpy.context.object
    coll_cube.name = "collCube"

    # Calc number of cubes needed to cover curve
    cube_offset = 1.5
    cube_count = self.length()/(EDGE_LENGTH*cube_offset)

    # Modifiers used to place cubes along curve in an array of objects
    arrayMod = coll_cube.modifiers.new(name='CollCubeArray', type='ARRAY')
    arrayMod.relative_offset_displace[0] = cube_offset
    curveMod = coll_cube.modifiers.new(name='CollCubeCurve', type='CURVE')
    curveMod.object = bpy.data.objects[self.curve_name]

    # Determine count from length        
    arrayMod.count = round(cube_count)-1 # Last and first collide too often

    # Set array as active object - so modifiers can be applied
    bpy.context.scene.objects.active = coll_cube
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier="CollCubeArray")
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier="CollCubeCurve")

    # Break array into separate cubes
    bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
    bpy.ops.mesh.separate(type='LOOSE')
    bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
    bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_GEOMETRY')

def collides(self):
    # Create sqherical boundary for each cube which will be used to find collisions
    collBounds = []
    for obj in bpy.data.objects:
        if obj.name.startswith("collCube"):
            o = CollSphere((EDGE_LENGTH/2), obj.location)
            collBounds.append(o)

    # Cycle through each to find collision
    collision = False
    cnt = 1                
    for i in range(0,len(collBounds)):
        if collision:
            print(cnt)
            return True
            #break
        else:
            for j in range(cnt,len(collBounds)):
                if collBounds[i].intersect(collBounds[j]):
                    #print("collision")
                    collision = True
                    break
                else:
                    #print("no collision")
                    continue
        cnt += 1


def create(name, size, station):
    c = NURBSCurve(name,size,station)
    c.buildCurve()
    curveLength = c.length()
    c.collCubes()
    #c.fill()

    # Loop through all segments and find angles using calcAngle()
    prev = (0,0,0,0)
    #tooSharp = 0
    for i in range(0,(len(c.coords)-2)): 
        curr = c.coords[i]
        next = c.coords[i+1]
        angle = calcAngle(prev,curr,next)
        prev = curr
        if angle < 25:
            print("unviable angle")
            return
        elif angle >= 25 and angle <= 35:
            print("workable angle")
        #tooSharp += 1

    # If a track collision, toss individual
    if c.collides():
        print("Collides")
        return
    else:
        print("Doesn't collide")
        viableIndividuals.append(c.coords)
        #print(viableIndividuals[0])


# Control point(CP) array (initialized with start pos for 'station')
start_pos = [(1,0,0,1),(2,0,0,1)] #,(5,0,5,1),(6,0,5,1)

count = 1

#for count in range(1,3):
#while len(viableIndividuals) < 2:
clearScene(("Curve"+str(count)))
create(("Curve"+str(count)),15,start_pos)
#count+=1


print("END END END")
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved by updating Blender. 2.76 didn't have the `do_unlink=True` argument for `obj.remove()` that 2.78 does.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not crash for me, but maybe if you unlink the object from the scene before clearing it would work better:

```
import bpy


# Clears all existing objects and meshes
def clearScene():
    for obj in bpy.data.objects:
        if obj.name.startswith("Cube"):
            bpy.context.scene.objects.unlink(obj)
            obj.user_clear()
            bpy.data.objects.remove(obj)
    for mesh in bpy.data.meshes:
        bpy.data.meshes.remove(mesh)

class myCube:
    def __init__(self,size,pos):
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(radius=size/2,location=pos)


myCubes = []
x = 0

for i in range(0,9):
    clearScene()
    c = myCube(2,(x,0,0))
    myCubes.append(c)
    x += 1
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I did actually get this example working with `.unlink()` however this then creates another problem in my actual script where the object isn't in the Scene. Basically I am trying to create randomized roller-coasters with NURBS curves and then test for viability. When I try to unlink "Curve" from the scene it says it isn't present there, even though it has been linked in an executed method `buildCurve()`. I have put full script in my original post if you'd mind taking a look? Cheers